# In splide js when we give slider arrows according to break point, and when we do page zoom and by doing (ctrl+0) , arrows were removed from DOM

Tags: accessibility, breakpoints, wcag, splidejs

In splide js when we give slider arrows according to break point, and when we do page zoom upto 300% and by doing (ctrl+0) reset zoom, arrows were removed from DOM.
steps:
give slider options as arrows true in different breakpoints.
zoom the page upto 300%.
hit (ctrl+0) reset zoom.

now arrows will be removed from DOM.

arrows should still present in DOM according to breakpoint.

{
"gap": "16px",
"perPage": "3",
"arrows": true,
"pagination": true,
"arrowPath": "M18.2325 24L21.81 20.4225H13.8217V18.7558H21.81L18.2325 15.1783L19.4108 14L25                   19.5892L19.4108 25.1783L18.2325 24Z",
"sliderArrowsCtr": false,
"breakpoints": {
"767": {
"arrows": true,
"pagination": true,
"numbers": true,
"perPage": "1"
},
"1279": {
"pagination": true,
"arrows": true,
"numbers": false,
"perPage": "2"
},
"1919": {
"arrows": true,
"numbers": false
}
}
}

Comment: I tried the examples on https://splidejs.com/premium/ and they all worked fine when zoomed in then resetting the zoom. Do you have a working example that shows the problem?